# needing "MarkerMetro.Unity.Pathfinding.Ionic.Zip" package supporting UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I've a [pre-built class library](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) on classic full.net referencing `"MarkerMetro.Unity.Pathfinding.Ionic.Zip"` nugget package. Now I want to port this class library to .net core to be able to use it in my UWP application. But when I try to add `"MarkerMetro.Unity.Ionic.Zlib"` Package to .net core class library, I get this error:

`Package MarkerMetro.Unity.Pathfinding.Ionic.Zip 2.0.0.14 is not compatible with netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6).`

Is there any `MarkerMetro.Unity.Pathfinding.Ionic.Zip` package supporting .NetStandard?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - no there isn't a `MarkerMetro.Unity.Pathfinding.Ionic.Zip` nuget package that supports .NetStandard

The answer is not that straightforward. You need to do some reading to understand what is .NET Standard and what each version really means and how to port from .NET Framework to .NET Core

[.NET Standard Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)

[Porting to .NET Core from .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/index)